Sum of the individual kinetic energies of the particles which make the system the same as the K.E. of the center of mass? What's bad in my reasoning?
I have one idea, but I'm not sure it's true.
According to Newton's second law, we have:
$$ F_{ext} = \sum m_i \cdot a_i \tag{1}$$
(where $i$ denotes all the particles of the system), or:
$$F_{ext} = m_T \cdot a_{cm} \tag{2}$$
where $m_T$ is the total mass of the system and $a_{cm}$ the acceleration of the center of mass of the system.
Accordingly we can integrate $(1)$ and $(2)$ with respect to the position $x$ and have, on the LHS, the work of the forces external to the system, and have:

on the RHS of $(1)$, $\Delta$ of the sum of the individual kinetic energies of all the particles of the system
on the RHS of $(2)$ - and this is the result I doubt the accuracy of - $\Delta$ of the kinetic energy of the center of mass of the system (in other words: $\frac{1}{2}m_T \cdot {v_{cm,f}} ^2- \frac{1}{2}m_T \cdot {v_{cm,i}} ^2$).

I have a doubt for the second formula, not on the $\Delta$ but on what's inside the $\Delta$ (i.e. $\frac{1}{2}m_T \cdot {v_{cm}} ^2$).
If somebody could tell me whether the work of the forces external to the system is indeed equal to $\frac{1}{2}m_T \cdot {v_{cm,f}} ^2- \frac{1}{2}m_T \cdot {v_{cm,i}} ^2$, I'd be grateful. Also I'd like to know whether my above derivation is correct.
Note: This all takes place in an inertial frame.

EDIT:
Here's the reasoning that led me to think that the total kinetic energy is the KE of the center of mass:
I start from $(2)$: $$F_{ext} + F_{int} = m_T \cdot a_{cm}$$
Then: $$\int (F_{ext} + F_{int}) d s = m_T \int a_{cm} \cdot d s$$
$$W_{ext} + W_{int}= m_T \int dv_{cm} \frac{d s}{dt}$$
$$W_{ext} + W_{int}= m_T \int v_{cm} dv_{cm}$$
$$W_{ext} + W_{int}= \Delta (\frac{1}{2} m_T \cdot {v_{cm}}^2)$$
Note I have integrated along the path followed by the Center of Mass of the system. So that means that $W_{int}$ and $W_{ext}$ are taken along the trajectory of the CM.
I know it's unsual, but I think it is correct (provided we've defined correctly along which path everything is taken).
I am not sure it is $100$% useful though. For instance, in the case of the example of Farcher (see answer below) we get $0=0$ with my relation (since the CM does not move at all).

The two equations are the net external force on the system of particles. How are you getting from there to the kinetic energies? In any case the answer to the first question in the title of your post is no since it t doesn’t include the kinetic energies of the random motions of the particles with respect to the center of mass of the system of particles

So, the work of the external forces is neither the difference of the sum of the individual kinetic energies, neither the difference of the K.E. of the center of mass. If I get it well, both lack the Work of the internal forces? (your notes are really helpful, basics!)

Velocity is a vector, energy is a scalar (being related to v^2).  Try using momentum (as a vector which has the direction of v) so that opposite momentums cancel.

The flaw in your reasoning is that $dW = \sum F_i \cdot ds_i$. You're trying to factor out the $ds$ and say that $dW=\left( \sum F_i\right) ds$, but you can't factor out $ds$ because it's not the same $ds$ for each force. Each force is being applied through a different path. And since you have different $ds$, you can't just integrate.

A simple example to show that the kinetic energy of the CoM is not the same as the sum of the kinetic energies of the particles which make up the system is the centre of mass being stationary and the two equal mass particles which make up the system moving away from one another along a line which passes through the centre of mass at the same speed.


Sum of the individual kinetic energies of the particles which make the
system the same as the K.E. of the center of mass?

No.
The total kinetic energy consists of two parts.
One is the kinetic energy associated with the collective motion of the particles (the center of mass) with respect to an external (to the center of mass) reference frame. An example is the kinetic energy of the COM of a ball in motion with respect to the ground.
The other is the kinetic energy associated with the random molecular motions of the individual particles with respect to the center of mass of the system of particles. For the ball, that would be the random motions of the molecules of the ball. This is the KE associated with the temperature of an object.
Hope this helps.

Is it usual to neglect the kinetic energy associated with the temperature in early newtonian mechanics classes ? Also, if I understand correctly, in my question, my LHS work is incorrect (it doesn't include internal forces work) but my RHS is correct provided we are neglecting the KE associated with the temperature ?

@niobium "Is it usual to neglect the kinetic energy associated with the temperature in early newtonian mechanics classes ?". Yes. Because those classes are focused on mechanical energy, i.e., the KE and PE associated with the object as a whole. The KE and PE at the molecular level is typically introduced in thermodynamics.

“Also, if I understand correctly, in my question, my LHS work is incorrect (it doesn't include internal forces work) but my RHS is correct provided we are neglecting the KE associated with the temperature ?” Your integration of the LHS and RHS only deal with mechanical kinetic energy, and not internal (molecular) kinetic energy. My only point is the total KE of an object is not only its mechanical KE but also its internal (molecular) KE.

If we divide a body into multiple elemental masses $dm$ and each elemental mass of the body is having variable velocity $v$($v$ varies throughout the body) then the total kinetic energy is
$$K=\frac12\int_0^mv^2dm$$
Meanwhile, the "kinetic energy of center of mass" which you defined in your question as a function of the total mass and velocity of centre of mass, is
$$K_{\text{com}}=\frac12\left(\int_0^mdm\right)\left(\frac{\int_0^m v dm}{\int_0^mdm}\right)^2$$$$=\frac12\frac{\left(\int_0^m v dm\right)^2}{\int_0^mdm}$$
So unless they somehow turn out to be equal depending on how $v$ varies throughout the total mass, the answer to your titular question is no.
P.S.: For translational motion in rigid bodies, where each particle shows the same velocity, they turn out to be equal.
P.S.S: Bob D mentioned the internal energies of the system too in the comments but I wrote this answer considering no thermodynamic change($\Delta Q=\Delta U=0$) as done in high school mechanics courses.

This is WRONG! There is no such a quantity as the kinetic energy of the center of mass. It's never defined, because it's useless in mechanics: it doesn't come from any manipulation of principles and derived equations. It's a useless and dangerous definition

@basics I defined "kinetic energy of centre of mass" as mentioned in the question, will edit my answer to include that

"For rigid bodies, where each particle shows the same velocity" do mean for rigid bodies, in translational motion ?

@niobium yes, but you can use the first formula for rotating bodies too

As @accumulation points out, the path in space over which the force is integrated is the problem.

(Just in case it is not clear) if the constituent parts are at rest in the center-of-mass system, the reasoning is correct and the sum of the kinetic energies are the same.

If the constituent parts are not at rest then they already have some kinetic energy, and the work done on them by the force along the path is not the work done on them bringing them from rest to their final velocities. But it is the change in kinetic energy! However, a change in something is not the same as its absolute value unless it starts from zero.



Since the kinetic energy is not linear in the velocity, there's no such a law for the kinetic energy of the center of mass.
The theorem of kinetic energy reads
$$\frac{d K}{d t} = P^{tot}$$
being $K$ the kinetic energy of the system, and $P^{tot} = P^{i} + P^{e}$ the total power, both internal and external, of the actions on the system.
If you integrate in time, you get
$$\Delta K = K(t_1) - K(t_0) = W^{tot} \ ,$$
being $W^{tot} = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} P^{tot}(\tau) d\tau$ the total work.
